# How many search strings can fgrep handle?

Tags: grep, pattern-matching

I have a text file (about 1.5 gigabytes) that I want to search for occurrences of specific titles.  There are about 10 million titles in my list.

Obviously, not every title in the list will exist in the text file.  That's okay.  I just need to know which titles exist in the text.

Now, if it was just a couple hundred titles, I'd use `fgrep` and tell it to read the search strings from a file (i.e. `fgrep -f patternlist.txt bigtextfile.txt`).

But will `fgrep` choke on that much data?

It's a little bit of work to turn my titles list and the text file into a form that I could use with `fgrep`, so I'd like some idea of whether this is likely to work before I go to that effort.

Another option would be to split the titles list into multiple files and run `fgrep` once for each sub-list.  That's not crazy, provided that `fgrep` can handle a reasonably large number of search strings.  If it can handle 1 million, it's a no-brainer.  If it can't handle 100,000 (requiring over 100 individual runs), then it's a less attractive option.

So, anybody have experience using `fgrep` to search for a very large number of strings?  If not, is there some other program available?  I could write my own given a day or two, but if I can avoid the work . . .

Comment: As I said, it's a few hours' work getting my data into the proper format to try this. I was hoping somebody else had tried it before I spend the time.

Comment: Downvoter? It's customary to provide an explanatory comment.

Comment: Re "if it can't handle 100,000 (requiring over 100 individual runs), then it's a less attractive option", I'm not sure that would be *that* problematic since you'll probably be scripting the runs anyway. You could get the text in the format you want then have a script iterate over the search terms, 100000 at a time, and run the individual `grep` commands. It won't be like you have to type in each command manually. Process startup times may cause an issue if you wanted to do (say) one search term per process but 100000 at a time shouldn't have too much impact.

Answer (score 0):

`fgrep` scale very well using inventions like:

- [Efficient String: Matching An Aid to Bibliographic Search](http://www.google.com/search?q=Efficient+String+Matching+An+Aid+to+Bibliographic+Search)
- [A String Matching Algorithm Fast on the Average](http://www.google.de/search?q=A+String+Matching+Algorithm+Fast+on+the+Average)
- **Update:** [Fast Cache for Your Text: Accelerating Exact Pattern Matching with Feed-Forward Bloom Filters](http://www.google.com/search?q=Fast+Cache+for+Your+Text%3A+Accelerating+Exact+Pattern+Matching+with+Feed-Forward+Bloom+Filters)

Your pattern list is read, *compiled* and kept in memory, of course. The *big* input file can be memory mapped with `--mmap` option for optimal resource usage -- the kernel map the file into a memory region; the application itself do not know how but the whole file is accessible by a simple memory address.

Comment: Thank you. I'm familiar with how the algorithm works and have no doubt that it can match large numbers of strings efficiently. The question is whether fgreq can actually handle 10 million input strings without running out of memory, or taking an absurdly long time to build the DFA. At 1.5 gigabytes, I don't consider the input file especially large, and with sufficient memory the standard OS file caching should be sufficient.

Comment: The research project from Iulian Moraru and David G. Andersen (__Fast Cache for Your Text: Accelerating Exact Pattern Matching with Feed-Forward Bloom Filters__) gives a good impression about the boundries of existing (f)grep implementation. Myself, I never reached them.